# Переместить стороннюю программу в заданные координаты

Tags: c#, winapi

Есть главная программа (ГП), на ней есть панель. В эту панель я хочу встраивать стороннюю программу (СП).

СП запускается с параметрами (в данном контексте не важно с какими, но без них никак). И именно наличие параметров портит всё: появляются тормоза, не работают некоторые функции (указанные в коде ниже).

В том числе торможение от встраивания создает мерцание СП на экране (СП запускается, например, в центре экрана, а панель у ГП находится в другом месте).

В итоге приняли решение, что СП будет в числе прочих параметров принимать координаты панели, и изначально до момента отрисовки формы задавать начальное положение (костыль для избежания мелькания).

Поиск координат панели:

```c#
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}

Rect positionPanel = new Rect();
GetWindowRect(Panel.Handle, ref positionPanel);
Point PanelPoint = this.PointToScreen(new Point(positionPanel.Left, positionPanel.Top));
```

Запуск СП:

```c#
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process p = new Process();
psi.FileName = address;//address это путь для запуска СП
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//вот это из-за наличия параметров при запуске СП почему-то игнорируется
psi.Arguments = arguments + ";" + PanelPoint.X + ";" + PanelPoint.Y;//arguments это параметры для СП
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

Встраивание СП:

```c#
IntPtr handle = (IntPtr)0;
handle = FindWindow(null, Caption);//caption это заголовок главное окна СП
if (handle != (IntPtr)0)
{               
   SetParent(handle, Panel.Handle);
   MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, CurrentPanel.Width, CurrentPanel.Height, true); 
   //0, 0 потому что для встроенной СП родителем является панель,  
   //верхний левый угол панели это и есть 0, 0
 }
```

Данный код не работает. Проблема в том, что функция `GetWindowRect` дает координаты, а мне их надо как-то преобразовывать (в коде это попытка применения `this.PointToScreen`). Например, координата панели (100;150) - это полученная функцией `GetWindowRect`. А при передаче параметров для СП эта координата преобразуется в (130;200). То есть мерцание СП все равно есть. Пытались разобраться с относительными и абсолютными координатами, но плодов это не принесло.

Как встроить СП в панель ГП без мерцания?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, зачем вы используете `FindWindow`, если вы сами запустили этот процесс и ссылка на него у вас есть.

Предлагаю попробовать следующий код:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);



ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
p.WaitForInputIdle();

SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel.Handle);
MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, panel.Width, panel.Height, false);

const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
ShowWindowAsync(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

Обратите внимание на следующие моменты:

- Запуска приложения дожидаемся с помощью метода `WaitForInputIdle` вместо `Thread.Sleep`.
- Передвигаем окно, используя имеющуюся у нас ссылку на процесс.
- Перед стартом приложения задаём его окну стиль Minimized, чтобы избежать его мелькания. А после запуска распахиваем его.

Вместо максимизации окна можно вернуть его в нормальное состояние. Список кодов [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Не все понятно.

Что такое `Panel`? Какой у него тип?

теперь о строке

```
psi.Arguments = arguments + ";" + PanelPoint.X + ";" + PanelPoint.Y;
```

Во первых лучше сделать так

```
psi.Arguments = string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", arguments, PanelPoint.X, PanelPoint.Y);
```

или

```
psi.Arguments = arguments + ";" + PanelPoint.X.ToString() + ";" + PanelPoint.Y.ToString();
```

И почему параметры передаются через знак `";"`, а не через пробел? Зачем вообще передавать координаты, если координаты СП должны изменяться динамически? Вы уверены в правильности параметров запуска СП?

Чтобы устранить мерцание, попробуйте изменить строку

```
MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, CurrentPanel.Width, CurrentPanel.Height, false);
```

В какой момент происходит мерцание? В момент запуска? Или в момент перемещения ГП?

Если Вы являетесь разработчиком и ГП и СП, то почему бы не предусмотреть взаимодействие (например на уровне WCF)?

Опять же, если вы разработчик обоих приложений, почему бы вам не вынести все ядро СП в библиотеку и не использовать ее в ГП?